# Parse and remove special characters in java regex

Tags: java, regex

So we were looking at some of the other regex posts and we are having trouble removing a special case in one instance; the special character is in the beginning of the word.

We have the following line in our code:

```
String k = s.replaceAll("([a-z]+)[()?:!.,;]*", "$1");
```

where s is a singular word. For example, when parsing the sentence "(hi hi hi)" by tokenizing it, and then performing the replaceAll function on each token, we get an output of:

```
(hi
hi
hi
```

What are we missing in our regex?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an easier approach - replace the characters that you do *not* want with spaces:

```
String k = s.replaceAll("[()?:!.,;]+", " ");
```

Comment: Thanks, i guess I was overthinking it. I also replaced it with "" instead of " "

Answer (score 0):

Position matters so you would need to match the excluded charcters *before* the capturing group also:

```
String k = s.replaceAll("[()?:!.,;]*([a-z]+)[()?:!.,;]*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

your replace  just removed the "special chars" after the `[a-z]+`, that's why the `(` before `hi` is left there.

If you know `s` is a **single** word
you could either:

```
String k = s.replaceAll("\\W*(\\w+)\\W*", "$1");
```

or

```
String k = s.replaceAll("\\W*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be more simple

try this :

```
String oldString = "Hi There @#$ What is %#your name?@#$@#$ 0123$$"; 
System.out.println(oldString.replaceAll("[\\p{Punct}\\s\\d]+", " ");
```

output : 
Hi There What is your name 0123

So it also accepts numeric. 
    .replaceAll("[\p{Punct}\s\d]+", " "); 
will replace alll the Punctuations used which includes almost all the special characters.