# Getting scanner to read text file

Tags: java

I am trying to use a scanner to read a text file pulled with `JFileChooser`. The `wordCount` is working correctly, so I know it is reading. However, I cannot get it to search for instances of the user inputted word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a  word");
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File fileSelection = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
    int wordCount = 0;
    int inputCount = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner (fileSelection);
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String word = s.next();
        if (word.equals(input)) {
            inputCount++;
    }
    wordCount++;
}
```

Comment: Give us an example of your file content and an input.

Comment: How are you displaying the inputCount?  Do you update it on some GUI?

Comment: have it printing to console. I think it might be because the word is followed by a period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to look for

, ; . ! ? etc.

for each word.  The `next()` method grabs an entire string until it hits an `empty space`.

It will consider "hi, how are you?" as the following "hi,", "how", "are", "you?".

You can use the method `indexOf(String)` to find these characters.  You can also use replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) to replace characters.  You can individuality remove each character or you can use a `Regex`, but those are usually more complex to understand.

```
//this will remove a certain character with a blank space
word = word.replaceAll(".","");
word = word.replaceAll(",","");
word = word.replaceAll("!","");
//etc.
```

Read more about this method:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Here's a Regex example:

```
//NOTE:  This example will not work for you.  It's just a simple example for seeing a Regex.
//Removes whitespace between a word character and . or ,
String pattern = "(\\w)(\\s+)([\\.,])";
word = word.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$3");
```

Source:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Here is a good Regex example that may help you:

[Regex for special characters in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530942/regex-for-special-characters-in-java)

[Parse and remove special characters in java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857360/parse-and-remove-special-characters-in-java-regex)

[Remove all non-"word characters" from a String in Java, leaving accented characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611979/remove-all-non-word-characters-from-a-string-in-java-leaving-accented-charact)

Comment: Is there a way to have the scanner ignore that punctuation?

Comment: I think the approach I provided is more comprehensive, since everything get's accepted with `.*`. The replaceAll approach would get problems with unspecified special signs. In this special case `;` or some foreign signs.

Comment: This approach will let the user customize the characters he/she wants to remove specifically.

Answer (score 0):

if the user inputed text is different in case then you should try using `equalsIgnoreCase()`

Comment: I think it might be because the word is followed by a period. Is there a way to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to blackpanthers answer you should also use trim() to account for whitespaces.as
"abc" not equal to "abc "

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `matches()`.

`equals` will not help you, since `next()` doesn't return the file word by word,
but rather whitespace (**not** comma, semicolon, etc.) separated token by token (as others mentioned).

Here the java doc
[String#matches(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)

...and a little example.

```
input = ".*" + input + ".*";
...
boolean foundWord = word.matches(input)
```

`.` is the regex wildcard and stands for any sign. `.*` stands for 0 or more undefined signs. So you get a match, if input is somewhere in `word`.